# Eclipse only sees JDK with sudo

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sudo

I have to start by saying that I have just switched to Ubuntu from Windows and I am new to Linux in general. Coming from Windows, I really am not familiar with how exactly the permissions work, the Linux file system, where I am able to create folders that I can use without the `sudo` command etc.

I use eclipse on a daily basis for android development and other simple java swing projects. I was able to download and extract the latest available version of eclipse (kepler) to this path: `/opt/eclipse`. Inside this directory is the eclipse executable and other eclipse related files.

I also installed the JDK and verified with the `java -version` command. It says:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am running on a 64 bit CPU architecture so both programs are the 64 bit version.

Now, my problem is that if I open eclipse from the Unity dash or from the file explorer, it give me this error:

[image]

However if I run `sudo eclipse` in the terminal, everything runs just fine as long as I do it as the super user. I have a hunch that the JDK is installed in a folder that is restricted to normal users and only works if I run the `sudo` command but this is just a hunch. As I said, I am new to Linux and I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here, I am learning as I go. I need a good explanation as to how to make it start from the Unity dock without the `sudo` command. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the permission on /usr/lib/jvm ?

Comment: Check if these commands work and what they say: `which java` `which javac` `java -version` `javac -version`. Also check how the path is set for user: `echo $PATH`

Comment: 'which java' outputs: '/usr/bin/java' , 'which javac' outputs: '/usr/bin/javac'

Comment: yes,I guess the path I added in eclipse.ini file was not correct after all. So I had the wrong path to the JDK. Post an answer so I can mark it as accepted. And Thank you

Comment: maybe change the path in eclipse under "Installed JREs" in the settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after running the `which java` cmd, I noticed that the path to the JDK from the `eclipse.ini` file was not pointing to the correct location. I fixed the path and now it works. I don't know how the `sudo`  cmd overrides the eclipse.ini path to JDK but well, it works

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `chmod` command from the terminal to change the permissions on the Java folder.  See this link for more information:
http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

Comment: Well it seems I had the wrong path to the JDK added to eclipse.ini file